# Undefined value in forEach function in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is my document:

```
{
"CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2017-09-26T06:39:29.105Z"),
"DeviceId" : "89984320001499681816",
"UserId" : UUID("bca0db12-2246-49a5-8703-b03fee45e50f"),
"FirstName" : " ",
"LastName" : "",
}
```

some of my this documents , "**FirstName**" and "**LastName**" were filled. but all documents have **DeviceId**.

I write this query and I want to pass an object to a method that has a Filled FirstName .

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : {
     FirstName : 
         {$nin : [" "]}
            }
  },
 {$group: {_id : "$DeviceId" }
 },{
 $project: {
     "DeviceId" : 1
 }}
 ]).forEach(
  function(obj)
    {
      print(
      "Orginal Coll \nDeviceId: " + obj.DeviceId
      +" \nFirstName: "   + obj.FirstName
      +" \nLastName: "    + obj.LastName)
      //compareCollection(obj);

});
```

but I got this at the end:

```
Orginal Coll 
DeviceId: undefined 
FirstName: undefined 
LastName: undefined
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues with this command:

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : { FirstName: { $nin : [" "] } } },
 {$group: {_id : "$DeviceId" } },
 {$project: { "DeviceId" : 1 } }
])
```

1. The `$match` stage will not match the document supplied in your question because the document you supplied has `"FirstName" : " "` so that document would be matched by `$in` but not by `$nin`
2. If the `$match` stage was changed to `$in` then it would emit a document and the grouping stage would have something to work on but the grouping stage is only configured to return an `_id` attribute so it returns the following intermediate document:

   ```
   {
       "_id" : "89984320001499681816"
   }
   ```
3. The `$project` stage attempts to project `"DeviceId"` but the result of the grouping stage contains **only** an `_id` attribute so you cannot project a `DeviceId` attribute from that document.
4. By the time your aggregation pipeline reaches the `forEach` funciton there is no DeviceId, FirstName or LastName attribute in the documents.

To further understand what's happening inside the aggregation pipeline you could run this query:

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : { FirstName: { $in : [" "] } } },
 {$project: { "DeviceId" : 1, FirstName: 1, LastName: 1 } }
]).forEach(
  function(obj) {
      print(obj);
  }
);
```

Or, just run each stage in the pipeline on its own and review the output of each state since that becomes the input to the next stage. So, for example:

This command ...

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : { FirstName: { $in : [" "] } } }
])
```

... returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d13b64c26584cd8b7a15c8"),
    "CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2017-09-26T06:39:29.105Z"),
    "DeviceId" : "89984320001499681816",
    "UserId" : UUID("bca0db12-2246-49a5-8703-b03fee45e50f"),
    "FirstName" : " ",
    "LastName" : ""
}
```

This command ...

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : { FirstName: { $in : [" "] } } },
 {$group: {_id : "$DeviceId" } }
])
```

... returns:

```
{
    "_id" : "89984320001499681816"
}
```

This command ...

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : { FirstName: { $in : [" "] } } },
 {$group: {_id : "$DeviceId" } },
 {$project: { "DeviceId" : 1 } }
])
```

... returns:

```
{
    "_id" : "89984320001499681816"
}
```

This should make clear that once you add in the `$group` stage you lose the DeviceId, FirstName and LastName attributes hence they are not available for you to print in the `forEach` function.

Comment: thanks dude. But imagine I have 2 documents with same device Id but one of them `FirstName` field is empty.I want by ‍`group by‍` at first do filter documents and then By some condition I do filter and send the document that has a  filled FirstName to a method. what is your idia?

Comment: @sayres apologies I cannot follow your last comment. I think the above answer explains exactly why your `forEach` function is getting a document which does not have the state you expected. The answer also provides some tips on how to diagnose these issues yourself. If you still have an issue perhaps you could raise another question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least update your original question to provide a clear statement of your inputs, your desired end results and what you have tried so far?

Comment: dude your explanation was clear and I understand what's happen. thank you